# How to remove lines containing any one of many possible matches with grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I am using `grep -v "cat" input.txt > output.txt` to remove all lines in `input.txt` containing "cat" and outputing the result in `output.txt`. How can I remove all lines containing "cat" and/or "dog" and/or "fish" and/or "sheep"? This works, but requires many lines:

```
grep -v "cat" input.txt > output.txt
mv output.txt input.txt
grep -v "dog" input.txt > output.txt
mv output.txt input.txt
grep -v "fish" input.txt > output.txt
mv output.txt input.txt
grep -v "sheep" input.txt > output.txt
mv output.txt input.txt
```

I tried this `grep -v [cat|dog|fish|sheep] input.txt > output.txt, but that did not work.

How can I remove any line containing at least one of these items?

Comment: Your attempt is almost good: just use `egrep` instead, or escape each one of the pipes: `grep -v "cat\|dog..."`.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the pipes:

```
grep -v "cat\|dog\|fish\|sheep" input.txt > output.txt
```

Otherwise you can can tell `grep` to accept a perl-style regex with the option `-P <regex>`:

```
grep -v -P "(cat|dog|fish|sheep)" input.txt > output.txt
```